# JavaFX - Sequential Transition - playing back and forth (step by step)

Tags: java, animation, javafx, binary-search-tree, transition

I'm struggling with making an animation showing the searchin in Binary Search Tree in JavaFX.
The goal is to make a visualization of comparing the value of tree node with possibility to:

pause and play it any time
being able to play the animation backwards (to go at least one step back),
give a user an ability to play the animation step-by-step or whole at once.

[The preview of visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwlGu.png)

My vision was to make a series of TranslateTransitions(**TT**) added in one SequentialTransition(**ST**). If the animation is marked as "step-by-step" the each TT pauses the whole ST in their OnFinished handler. However this kinda works only for going one-way.

My question is. ***What is the best approach to maintain going fluent and step-by-step animation in reverse direction ?***

I was thinking about:

- maybe making another sequence of inverse transitions (but how to tell
  it from which step to  continue ?)
- somehow work with rate property ? is it possible to change it while the ST is running ?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can change the rate property of an `Animation` while it is in progress. The idea of using a `SequentialTransition` is appealing, but it doesn't work as easily as you might think. The problem arises when the sequential transition is paused at the boundary between two individual transitions: you don't have any way to tell which of the individual transitions is considered the current one (i.e. the next one or the previous one). So when you try to reverse the rate and play, the sequential transition can get confused and immediately think it's at the end of the one it's trying to play.

You might be able to hack this a little by using `Animation.getCurrentTime()` and `Animation.jumpTo(...)` to "nudge" the sequential transition a tiny amount in the correct direction before starting to play any step, but I think it's probably easier just to manage the individual transitions on their own instead of using a `SequentialTransition`.

Here's a simple example of using this technique to move a rectangle around:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.Animation.Status;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ReverseSequentialTransitionTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50, 250, 150);
        rect.setFill(Color.color(.5, .5, .1));
        pane.getChildren().add(rect);

        TranslateTransition ttForward = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), rect);
        ttForward.setFromX(0);
        ttForward.setToX(400);
        TranslateTransition ttDown = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), rect);
        ttDown.setFromY(0);
        ttDown.setToY(100);
        TranslateTransition ttBackward = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), rect);
        ttBackward.setFromX(400);
        ttBackward.setToX(0);
        TranslateTransition ttUp = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), rect);
        ttUp.setFromY(100);
        ttUp.setToY(0);

        List<Animation> transitions = Arrays.asList(ttForward, ttDown, ttBackward, ttUp);
        IntegerProperty nextTransitionIndex = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        Button playButton = new Button("Play Forward");
        playButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            int index = nextTransitionIndex.get();
            Animation anim = transitions.get(index);
            anim.setOnFinished(evt -> nextTransitionIndex.set(index+1));
            anim.setRate(1);
            anim.play();
        });

        Button reverseButton = new Button("Play backward");
        reverseButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            int index = nextTransitionIndex.get()-1;
            Animation anim = transitions.get(index);
            anim.setOnFinished(evt -> nextTransitionIndex.set(index));
            anim.setRate(-1);
            anim.play();
        });

        // This is not really part of the answer to the current question, but the
        // next three statements just disable the buttons when appropriate.

        // This is a binding which is true if and only if any of the transitions are
        // currently running:

        BooleanBinding anyPlaying = createAnyPlayingBinding(transitions);

        // Disable playButton if we are at the end of the last transition, or if
        // any transitions are playing:

        playButton.disableProperty().bind(
                nextTransitionIndex.greaterThanOrEqualTo(transitions.size())
                .or(anyPlaying)
        );

        // Disable reverseButton if we are at the beginning of the first transition,
        // or if any transitions are currently playing:

        reverseButton.disableProperty().bind(
                nextTransitionIndex.lessThanOrEqualTo(0)
                .or(anyPlaying));

        HBox controls = new HBox(5);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        controls.getChildren().addAll(playButton, reverseButton);


        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(pane);
        root.setBottom(controls);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private BooleanBinding createAnyPlayingBinding(List<Animation> transitions) {
        return new BooleanBinding() {
            { // Anonymous constructor
                // bind to the status properties of all the transitions
                // (i.e. mark this binding as invalid if any of the status properties change)
                transitions.stream()
                    .map(Animation::statusProperty)
                    .forEach(this::bind);
            }
            @Override
            protected boolean computeValue() {
                // return true if any of the transitions statuses are equal to RUNNING:
                return transitions.stream()
                    .anyMatch(anim -> anim.getStatus()==Status.RUNNING);
            }
        };

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

In JDK 7, the event handler for the `playButton` looks like this:

```
playButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        final int index = nextTransitionIndex.get();
        Animation anim = transitions.get(index);
        anim.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent evt) {
                nextTransitionIndex.set(index + 1) ;
            }
        });
        anim.setRate(1);
        anim.play();
    }
});
```

and similarly for `reverseButton`. You will need to declare a couple of things as `final` as well. The `createAnyPlayingBinding` method is something like

```
private BooleanBinding createAnyPlayingBinding(final List<Animation> transitions) {
    return new BooleanBinding() {
        { 
            for (Animation transition : transitions) {
                this.bind(transition.statusProperty();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected boolean computeValue() {
            // return true if any of the transitions statuses are equal to RUNNING:
            for (Animation anim : transitions) {
                if (anim.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) {
                    return true ;
                }
            }
            return false ;
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your example, I'm starting getting into it, but I'm little bit confused about that binding method. What does it exactly do ? Can you post please just a short comment ?
PS: I'm forced to use a JDK7, so I unfortunately can't use those method references :(

Comment: Added comments. Those are not really part of the answer to the question you asked, just keeps the disable state of the buttons correct. It's quite a bit uglier without lambdas, streams, and method references, but the translation is easy enough.